# MySQL - Select row number of a record

Tags: mysql, row-number

I have a table in MySQL populated as follows. Now I need to select the row number of a record in its sorted order. For example, the row number of words starting with `'c'` should be `4`.

```
Words
=====
coffee
banana
apple
cherry
blackberry
```

I tried the following query, but I get wrong results. Here `dict` is the table name and `words` is the column name.

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 id FROM (SELECT * FROM dict ORDER BY words) d,(SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE d.words LIKE CONCAT('c','%')
```

For the above query, I am getting the row numbers for the outer query. But I want the row numbers of the internal query. I do not know how to get that.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Some reading: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this perhaps:

```
SET @rownum = 0;
SELECT id 
FROM (SELECT *, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS id FROM dict ORDER BY words) d
WHERE d.words LIKE CONCAT('c','%')
```

As single query, try this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM (SELECT *, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS id FROM dict, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r ORDER BY words) d
WHERE d.words LIKE CONCAT('c','%')
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, this query works perfectly. But I am not able to execute two queries at once in PHP. So can you modify the queries to run as a single query?

Comment: I got it myself. SELECT id FROM (SELECT *, (at)rownum:=(at)rownum + 1 AS id FROM dict,(SELECT @rownum:=0) r ORDER BY words) d WHERE d.words LIKE CONCAT('b','%');

Comment: Awesome, I just came up to the same solution :)

Comment: When I execute the same query in PHP, I get this error `Every derived table must have its own alias`. Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: this row number is calculated before it executes the order by clause. If you have any order by clause in your statement then you can see row number in a different order