# Update data inside MySQL by cell location

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table as following (an example for sake of this question):

```
col
-----
data1
data2
data3
data1
data4
```

There are two appearances for `data1` (in row 1 and row 4). I want to change the `data1` in *fourth row* to `data5` (say).

Now I do know that the update command is:

```
update table_name set col = data5 where col = data1;
```

But this will change `data1` to `data5` both in row 1 and row 4. But I want to change it only in row 4.

I also do know about `limit` keyword which would go like this:

```
update table_name set col = data5 where col = data1 limit = 1;
```

Now although it will change the updating process to update a value just once, but it will always change first occurrence of value (in this case the value in row 1). But I want to change the value in row 2.

Further, since there is only one column, I cannot reference the `where` to some other column's value.

So is there some workaround for this? Something that uses the location of cell (row4, column1) sort of argument?

Comment: It is possible but need one more column for identify

Comment: I know about that possibility. If I interpreted you correctly, you mean we will use something like "update table_name set col = data5 where some_other_column = something_else;" right? But I would like to know if its possible with just one column. Plus what if the other column also has same values in those rows (row 1 and 4)?

Comment: AFAIK there is no "row record number" in mysql, you'll have to add an unique id as already stated by Mukesh

Comment: see also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235003/mysql-select-row-number-of-a-record

Comment: ok, thanks for info. I'll try creating a new temporary column and workaround using that. Actually this question is a part of java frontend application with mysql backend. Still, thanks for clarifying. EDit: checking out that link